# How to run each site under a different user?

Tags: security, web-server, web-hosting, suexec

Let's say I have a server and a bunch of developers working on different sites(php and django) and I don't want the different developers to access each other's sites.

How should I go about implementing such a solution? (some pointers will do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think, under apache [suEXEC](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/suexec.html) will do the job.

Answer (score 4):

suPHP does this very well. There is a solution with Apache by using setuid and setgid.

Comment: Yes, for the PHP stuff suPHP should do the trick well. This way the PHP scripts only need to be readable for to the developers own accounts, as PHP will execute with respective users permissions.

Comment: That's exactly it !

Answer (score 0):

You need to chroot your FTP uploads (easy in Proftpd). If it is SCP uploads, you must make SSH directory chrooted (special patches needed).

Answer (score 0):

Antoine is right. You can check this link for setting up a apache-suphp webserver.

http://techtrunch.com/installations/compile-apache-suphp-ubuntu

> suPHP is a tool for executing PHP
>   scripts with the permissions of their
>   owners. It consists of an Apache
>   module (mod_suphp) and a setuid root
>   binary (suphp) that is called by the
>   Apache module to change the uid of the
>   process executing the PHP interpreter.

In suphp configuration the files must be in the ownership of the user, other wise php file requests will end up in Internal Server error.

Answer (score -1):

if you are talking about through just ftp, thats file system permissions that controls that.

Comment: No, they don't.